# Objective C - Swipe to delete triggers button in tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delete-row

I have a tableview where the user can edit the cell content by tapping the cell using a button. When I use the swipe to delete function the 'edit button' gets triggered and causes the app to crash. How can I make shure other buttons in the cell are disabled when I 'swipe to delete'?

**EDIT: example code added.**

CustomCell.h:

```
@interface CustumCell : UITableViewCell {
   UILabel *cellText;
   UIButton *editButton;
 }

 @property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *cellText;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *editButton;

 @end
```

CustomCell.m:

```
@implementation CustumCell
@synthesize cellText,editButton;

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cellText = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    cellText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    [self.contentView addSubview:cellText];

    //Cell Constraints
    NSArray *verticalConstraintsCell =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-6-[cellText(>=31)]"
                                        options: 0
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cellText)];


    NSArray *horizontalConstraintsCell =
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[cellText(>=2)]-50-|"
                                        options: 0
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cellText)];

     [self.contentView addConstraints:verticalConstraintsCell];
     [self.contentView addConstraints:horizontalConstraintsCell];

   editButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
   [self.contentView addSubview:editButton];

}
```

TableViewController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     CustumCell *cell= (CustumCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellSection1" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     if (cell==nil) {cell = [[CustumCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellSection1"];}

     // add cell content.. 

    //frame editButton:
    cell.editButton.frame= CGRectMake(tableView.frame.size.width/2, 0, tableView.frame.size.width/2-50, 43);
    [cell.editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell;

}
```

Now when I swipe to delete, the 'editButtonPressed' function executes.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating this button in code or in a storyboard/nib?

Comment: The button is created in code.

Comment: Edit: added example code.

Comment: Same problem here, were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are creating your button in code and adding it directly as a subview of the cell.  This will cause the behavior you're seeing.

When subclassing a `UITableViewCell` or `UICollectionView` cell you should not add views directly as subviews of `self`.  Instead, you must add them as subviews of `self.contentView`.

Comment: All the views in my custom cell are added as subviews of self.contentView?

Comment: Hmm, the constraints are probably what matter in this situation, can you include them?  It's a little odd that you're using constraints but you're also manually setting the frame of `editButton`.  Also, you seem to have editButton and checkButton, but only one is declared.  I assume this is just an issue with the code having some things removed.

Comment: I added the constraints and edited the example code. I just included one button (the editButton) in the example but I also have a checkbutton which has the same problem. I accidentally mixed them up in the example. Also I manually set the frames of some additional buttons because I never really had a problem with it, but I'm very new to objective C so I'm still figuring out a lot :). For the record, I only added constraints for the cellText, not for the editButton.

Comment: You should try adding constraints for the button.  If you don't then its frame will likely stay the same when the content view resizes, which may be causing your problem.

Comment: I removed the frames and added constraints for the buttons instead. Still got the same problem. I assume another way of doing this is to make a custom swipe to delete button and disable/hide the buttons when the gesture starts ('begin swipe')  but this seems a bit devious?

Comment: You really shouldn't have to, though.  I've used custom content inside a cell with swipe to delete plenty of times without that kind of fussing around.  There's something else going on.

Comment: Ok, I will try to figure out what is going on. I already broke my app down to just those two example buttons but still got the same problem. Thanks you for helping!